# Sql where condition on "as" column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query:

```
SELECT Param1, Param2 AS P1
FROM SomeTable
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
WHERE P1 > 2
```

There is way to do this?
Of course there is a query instead Param2.

Comment: why not use Param2 instead of P1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096301/sql-server-as-statement-aliased-column-within-where-statement

Comment: PERFORMANCE NOTE: the predicates in a `HAVING` clause are evaluated only AFTER the rows have been returned, as nearly the last step in the execution plan.  An equivalent predicate in the `WHERE` clause may be able to make use of an index to avoid searching every row for the condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH ABC
AS
(
SELECT Param1, Param2 AS P1
FROM SomeTable
)
SELECT * from ABC where P1>2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `having`

try this

```
select param1,param2 as p1
 from table
 having p1 > 2
```

Comment: I don't think so. This isn't even valid syntax

Answer (score 0):

instead of where use having clause..

```
    SELECT Param1, Param2 AS P1 
     FROM SomeTable 
     having P1>2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT Param1, P1
FROM
(
  SELECT Param1, Param2 AS P1
  FROM SomeTable
) src
WHERE P1 > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this, for a detailed explanantion:

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-use-a-select-list-alias-in-the-where-or-group-by-clause.html

Raj

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT Param1, 
[P1] = Param2
FROM SomeTable
WHERE [P1] > 2
```

If you're using ms sql this should work

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` wouldn't work. Common table as mentioned above is a good way to do it.