# how to add where condition in php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i am using the following query for getting the nearest place.But if i adding the where condition invalid where error comes.

```
SELECT
    attName,
    description,
    rating,
    COMMENT,
    latitude,
    langtitude,
    openingTime,
    closingTime,
    (
        (
            ACOS(
                SIN(".$lat." * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(".$lat." * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(
                    (".$lang." - langtitude) * PI() / 180
                )
            ) * 180 / PI()
        ) * 60 * 1.1515
    ) AS distance
FROM
    attraction
HAVING
    distance < 31
ORDER BY
    distance
```

If i am add the where condition error come.please help me how to add where condition for above query.

Comment: Wrap it with subquery and then add condition. I guess that you try `WHERE distance < ...`

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096301/sql-server-as-statement-aliased-column-within-where-statement It is for SQL Server but main idea is the same

Comment: Can you show us what query exactly causes a problem? You give a query that works, and tell us that when you do *something* that it won't work, but we do not know what you did.

Comment: You cannot use Having with Where, maybe you want to change your HAVING to WHERE?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `HAVING` clause with a `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT attName, description, rating, 
                COMMENT , latitude, langtitude, openingTime, closingTime,(
                (
                ACOS( SIN(  ".$lat." * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( latitude * PI( ) /180 ) + COS(  ".$lat." * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( latitude * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( (
                 ".$lang." - langtitude
                ) * PI( ) /180 ) ) *180 / PI( )
                ) *60 * 1.1515
                ) AS distance
                FROM attraction

                WHERE distance < 31

                ORDER BY distance
```

And then add addtional conditions as `AND this = that`

A `HAVING` clause is commonly used together with a `GROUP BY` - which you don't have.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ... HAVING ... ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Thank you for suggested me.Now i am using group by its working.thank you