# Alias unavailable in GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, alias

I have to group the `BaseIncidencia` column (sum the values), but it is unavailable. As said in [SQL Server AS statement aliased column within WHERE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096301/sql-server-as-statement-aliased-column-within-where-statement) it would be simple, but i don't have a column name to refer to. Only the alias.

```
BEGIN
SELECT @Artigo AS Artigo, T1.Contrib AS ContribID, YEAR(T1.Data) AS Ano, T3.DescricaoMes, CAST(ROUND(SUM(T1.Debito/0.23),2) AS decimal(16,2)) BaseIncidencia,
       CAST(ROUND(SUM(T1.Debito),2) AS decimal(16,2)) AS IVA, (CASE WHEN T5.Valid = 'True' THEN 'VALIDO' WHEN T5.Name = '---' THEN 'INEXISTENTE' ELSE 'INVALIDO' END) AS 'ValidadeNIF'
FROM  
#CONTAS_INI AS T1  
LEFT JOIN  
db.dbo.VatCheck T5 
ON T1.ContribuinteID = T5.VatNumber 
LEFT JOIN
#Meses AS T3
ON MONTH(T1.Data) = T3.Mes
GROUP BY T1.CntID, T1.ContribuinteID, YEAR(T1.Data), (CASE WHEN T5.Valid = 'True' THEN 'VALIDO' 
         WHEN T5.Name = '---' THEN 'INEXISTENTE' ELSE 'INVALIDO' END), T3.DescricaoMes
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN T5.Valid = 'True' THEN 'VALIDO' WHEN T5.Name = '---' THEN 'INEXISTENTE' ELSE 'INVALIDO' END), T1.ContribuinteID
END
```

I tried replacing the following line:

```
GROUP BY T1.CntID, T1.ContribuinteID, YEAR(T1.Data), (CASE WHEN T5.Valid = 'True' THEN 'VALIDO'
```

With:

```
GROUP BY T1.CntID, T1.ContribuinteID, YEAR(T1.Data), CAST(ROUND(SUM(T1.Debito/0.23),2) AS decimal(16,2)), (CASE WHEN T5.Valid = 'True' THEN 'VALIDO'
```

Only to get the `Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.` error.

So my question is, why i can't include `BaseIncidencia` alias in GROUP BY? And what's the workaround?

Comment: Have a look at [SELECT (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql), specifically "Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement". You'll notice that the GROUP BY is determined before the SELECT part of your query, thus, Column Alias's cannot be referred to in a GROUP BY. You would need to use the same expression in your GROUP BY as you did in your SELECT. Alternatively, you could use a `WITH` clause and not perform the aggregation inside it. Then you can aggregate outside of it and using Column Aliases that are returned from the `WITH` expression.

Comment: Use a subselect around it. Or put it into a CTE. You can only reference alias in order by

Comment: The deleted answer looks correct to me

Comment: Well i can't see the deleted answer. And i still have the problem.

Answer (score 3):

SQL is implemented as if a query was executed in the following order:

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

For most relational database systems, this order explains which names (columns or aliases) are valid because they must have been introduced in a previous step.

So in SQL Server, you cant use a term in the GROUP BY clause that you define in the SELECT clause because the GROUP BY is executed before the SELECT clause.

Comment: I understand that, and it makes sense. So what's the procedure to GROUP a column with the rows values added? Replacing `CAST(... BaseIncidencia` with something like `(SELECT SUM(T1 / 0.23) ....)`?

Comment: Probably subquery is the way to go.

Comment: you should use subquery to achieve alias in group by clause

Comment: Well i tried `(SELECT CAST(ROUND(SUM(T1.Debito/0.23),2) AS decimal(16,2))) AS BaseIncidencia`, but it is still not working. Shouldn't this SELECT return only 1 result?

Comment: let me see if i could find a working sample that meets your need.

Comment: take a look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ef321436-3417-4cca-b0ec-0f06f59a498c/invalid-column-name-for-group-by?forum=transactsql ... i hope it can help!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried this to group everything in the SELECT, but it still not working. `(SELECT X FROM (SELECT CAST(ROUND(SUM(T1.Debito/0.23),2) AS decimal(16,2)) AS X) AS BaseIncidencia GROUP BY X)` - No syntax errors, but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't group by the expression because it is an aggregate.  The group by values are used to determine the level at which an aggregate operates.

As a simplied example:

```
Select Count(*), 
       Object_id
From sys.columns
Group by Object_id
```

This is fairly easy to understand.  Count the number of column records for each object_id.

What you are trying to do would be the equivalent of

```
SELECT      COUNT( * ),
            object_id
  FROM      sys.columns
  GROUP BY  COUNT( * ),
            object_id
```

For the count of each object_id, give me the count of each object_id.  That doesn't make sense.

The error message you're getting:

```
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause
```

is telling you that you can't group by an aggregate expression.

Answer (score 0):

*Reposting 12th Dec.'s comment as an answer.*

You'll probably want to wrap your original `SELECT ... FROM ...` with `SELECT * FROM ( /*your original half*/ ) AS T`, leaving the `GROUP ... ORDER ...` parts to come after. This will allow you to reference any aliases produced at your inner `SELECT` in your `GROUP ... ORDER ...` parts.

However, since the `GROUP` moves to a different level, you'll have to move the aggregations like `SUM` to the new level as well. Also, you'll lose direct access to your tables, so mostly likely you'll have to change table aliases used in `GROUP ... ORDER ...` segments to `T`, plus making sure all columns the `GROUP ... ORDER ...` parts are using are produced in the inner `SELECT`. All this should be easy to handle though.